# Error making POST request to an API with Angular 2

Tags: api, angular, cors

I am trying to make a post request in my Angular 2 application. I am getting an error. I have a CORS plugin enabled and when I use Postman there requests are successful so no idea what might be wrong. I would appreciate any help :)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
16:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://website/api/v1/auth/sign_in. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import {User} from "./auth.model";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService{
    constructor(private http: Http){
    }

    signUp(user:User){
        const body= JSON.stringify(user);
        const headers= new Headers ({'Content-type':'application/json'});
        return this.http.post('https://website/api/v1/auth', body,{headers:headers})
            .map((response:Response)=> response.json())
            .catch((error: Response)=>Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

    signIn(user:User){
        const body= JSON.stringify(user);
        const headers= new Headers ({'Content-type':'application/json'});
        return this.http.post('https://website/api/v1/auth/sign_in', body,{headers:headers})
            .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
            .catch((error: Response)=>Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }


}
```

signin.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators,FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {User} from "./auth.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }


  onSubmit(){
    const user= new User(this.myForm.value.email, this.myForm.value.password);
    this.authService.signIn(user).subscribe();
    console.log("c");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm= new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
      ]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the third argument passed to the `http.post` method is a `RequestOptions object`

```
   const headers= new Headers ({'Content-type':'application/json'});
   const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
   this.http.post('https://website/api/v1/auth', user, options)
```

Also you should not need to stringify you object before sending it just send the user object as the body

You should also check to ensure that the server is returing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header

Comment: signIn(user:User){
        const headers= new Headers ({'Content-type':'application/json'});
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
        return this.http.post('https://website/api/v1/auth/sign_in', user,options)
            .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
            .catch((error: Response)=>Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

Comment: You should also check to ensure that the server is returing Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the header

Comment: actually can you also try using 'text/plain' instead and just using a string to see if that works

Comment: I have the CORS plugin enabled in the browser so it works without it. I checked on a get request.
When I used text/plain it gives me 401 unauthorised. It is the same when I use text/plain in postman. (with application json it works in postman with the same data) .hmm interesting

Comment: have you tried `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` and serialising the object

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).map((prop) => encodeURIComponent(property) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[property])
    ).join("&")`
this should serialise it

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I'm new here. How to upvote you? :) Why did it need to be serialized?

Comment: No probs. You have to up vote by click the upward pointing arrow and then check the tick to make it the chosen answer

Comment: you are basically reformatting the object into a string that that can then be deserialised back into an object on the server side `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` only accepts strings. check this out for more info https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/524c7e811e4abf9afe56